# Loading CSV File into SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, csv, visual-studio-2015

Working in the Visual Studio database feature. I've got two tables and I need to load a `.csv` file into them. I broke out the `.csv` file into my first and 2nd table. I'm trying a bulk insert

```
BULK INSERT Course
FROM 'E:\CourseInfo.csv'
WITH
(
     FIRSTROW = 2,
     FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
     ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
     TABLOCK
)
```

Everything seems right to me but I receive an error saying:

> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 2, column 3 (ID).

Here is a snippet of my `.CSV` file being used.

```
CourseID,CourseTitle,ID,
AC107,Accounting I,1,
AC107,Accounting I,2,
AC110,Payroll Accounting,3,
AC212,Taxation I,4,
AC212,Taxation I,5,
```

What is meant by mismatch or invalid char? I've tried removing all the values for column 'ID' but that still rendered the same error. I had ID set to auto-increment setting it as "isEntity" but have tried both ways with it set to true and false, still same error.

Possible error: Laid a huge egg, think I have to normalize this prior to doing this because there are multiples of the same class with different ID and that isn't right.

Comment: Since you mention T-SQL, which is Microsofts variant of the SQL language, I've changed your tags to remove mysql and add sql-server. If this was wrong, feel free to rollback

Comment: All Good I spaced out that part and just added the recommended tags Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To Answer my own question, I had my PK set to ID and it was showing up for Duplicate Rows where there was duplicate data. I have to remove duplicate courseID, and CourseTitle rows prior to populating my ID Column with values.